# preg_replace to catch the final string of numbers in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

Is there a clean way to get preg_replace to catch only the final string of numbers in a string? I'll be passing things like 'df14', 'asd32', '5ds3' etc, and I want it to only return '14', '32' and '3' from those.

I would use '/\D+(\d+)/' if the numbers were always preceded by nothing but non-numbers, but sometimes the string before the number can contain a number before the final series of numbers (as in the case of '5ds3' above). The string that comes before the number never ends with a number, however.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$str = preg_replace('/.*(\d+)$/', '$1', $str);`

Comment: No, that doesn't work at all. I'm passing an array containing: g1, g2, g3, g4, g5 etc through that preg_replace and get:

array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "1" } array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "0" } array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "0" [3]=> string(1) "1" } array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "0" [3]=> string(1) "0" [4]=> string(1) "2" } array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "1" (etcetera)

Comment: You should mention that you submit  an array and not elements from array in loop. And even with array I do not see any problem. Show exactly what do you use as input data.

Comment: Well, I'm submitting it like this:

`while ($shows = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {  $stripped[] = preg_replace('/\D+(\d+)/', '$1', $shows['post_name']); }`

at the moment. The array contains things like 'g1', 'bah3', '3mmo34', 'fsh13', etc. I want to keep the final number only. It works for all strings except the ones that start in '3mmo', obviously.

Comment: Show the content of `$shows['post_name']`. And I did not use `\D+`

Comment: Updated my previous comment. And no, you didn't. I did, which is what makes it work for all strings except the ones that start in '3mmo'.

Comment: Add modifier `/U` - look into answer. Updated for that case ('3mmo') too

Answer (score 1):

Even with array it works as expected. Show the data you have

```
$test = array(
 '23g1', 'g2', 'g34', 'g4', 'g5', '3mmo'
);

var_dump(preg_replace('/.*(\d+)?$/U', '$1', $test));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
preg_match('/.*(\d+)$/',...);
```